# On D&D Beyond, how to create a shield that gives a ranged attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew, dnd-beyond

In D&D Beyond, I’m trying to essentially create a captain America shield.  If I make its type a shield, then I can’t seem to make it give a ranged attack as an option.

I’ve tried to add a modifier and used the `Ranged Weapon Attack - Bludgeoning` modifier with a damage die roll and `dex` as the primary stat.  When equipped to a character the AC increases by 2 as it should for a shield, but no luck in getting a ranged attack to show up in the actions attack section of the character sheet.

Can anyone give me some direction in how to make this happen?  Does it need to be created as a weapon that gives an `AC` bonus to mimic what equipping a shield does?  Kind of feels like a hack. 
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you handling the timing of throwing/returning and the +2AC as well as the normal action requirement for donning/doffing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Try creating it off of a weapon template such as a javelin

I don't think you will be able to create what you want with a shield. However if you made it a weapon template, then added an AC bonus modifier when equipped, it would essentially function as the weaponized shield that you want.

Rename the text of the javelin to be your shield so it shows up how you want it on your character sheet!

I just ran through it real quick on my phone: When using the javelin template, add *Modifier Type: Bonus* and *Modifier Subtype: Armor Class* and you can give it the *Fixed Value* of *2*

**To add even further to it:** In order to make this truly Captain America's shield, you could create a Weapon Bond like the Eldritch Knight gains access to at the 3rd level

> Once you have bonded a weapon to yourself, you can't be disarmed of that weapon unless you are incapacitated. If it is on the same plane of existence, you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand.

So you could essentially throw it as a ranged weapon, have it teleport back into your hand, and still give you the +2 AC for having a shield. It should however be noted that your AC would be -2 once you throw it until it is back into your hand.

Comment: Instead of the Weapon Bond, you may want to look in the Artificer's returning weapon, which says `... and it returns to the wielder's hand immediately after it is used to make a ranged attack.`

Answer (score 3):

### This might not be possible

I'm not a *dndbeyond* guru, but it seems it isn't possible to get a separate action for this case: I've tried adding `Ranged Weapon Attack - Bludgeoning` like you've done as well as adding `Weapon Property: Thrown`. It is probably because of the `Armor - Shield` base item.
But you can still `Manage Custom` on a character's sheet (`Actions` tab) to add a custom action for throwing a shield.

Answer (score 0):

## Frame challenge

You're trying to create an item that functions as both shield and weapon, which D&D was not designed for. Will this shield function as a weapon for Dual Wielder feat and as shield for Shield Master at the same time?

Instead create an item which allows "special ranged attack" to be made with it, basing your wording on Shove attack.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your stated concerns. I was briefly playing a fighter who was attacking with their shield with Dual Wielder and didn't really find any issues. I think there are some concerns here that OP will need to figure out, but this one doesn't seem like a big one.

Comment: @NautArch Were the attack with the shield melee or ranged? You can see OP's item as Dwarven Thrower with AC boost instead of attack and damage. I'm assuming it's returning since _"(he is) trying to essentially create a captain America shield"_

Comment: Either way Extra Attacks + Bonus Attack from Dual Wielder or Shove from Shield Master (versatility) + all other goodies screams to me as power at no cost.

Comment: Well, there are costs here. THey are picking those fighting styles and feats in order to make it work.